# How to close connection available out of handle?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've built a lambda function for AWS in Python that uses `aiohttp` to make some requests.

As stated on AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html),

> Any declarations in your Lambda function code (outside the handler code, see Programming Model) remains initialized, providing additional optimization when the function is invoked again. For example, if your Lambda function establishes a database connection, instead of reestablishing the connection, the original connection is used in subsequent invocations.

so I placed `aiohttp.ClientSession()` outside of the handle function, so it may possibly be reused by future lambda functions:

```py
http_session = None

def handle(event, context):
    global http_session

    # http_session will be not None if context is reused
    if http_session is None:
        http_session = aiohttp.ClientSession()

    # [...] Use http_session here
```

However, I must close the connection with `await session.close()` after it's not being used anymore, which is, when the context is discarded. I cannot close `http_session` within `handle`, because it would totally nullify the possibility of the connection be reused.

Considering this, what options do I have?

1. Simply let the connection open and it will close by itself at some point.
2. There's a way of executing specific code at context drop.
3. There's no way to do what I want.

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: you are right. If you close it, it's not persistent connection anymore. I've never heard of a context drop hook. It's pretty safe to leave connection opened. Server closes the connection if it's not used after some time. The time after which the connection is closed (keep-alive timeout) is configured on the server side. The default value is different for every server. E.g. for apache it's only 5-10 seconds.

Comment: Well, if there's no real problem by letting the connection open, I think it's the way to go. Could you make an answer so I may accept it as the right answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I must close the connection with await session.close() after it's not being used anymore, which is, when the context is discarded. I cannot close http_session within handle, because it would totally nullify the possibility of the connection be reused.

yes, that's right. If you close it, it's not persistent connection anymore.

> 2. There's a way of executing specific code at context drop.

I've never heard of a context drop hook. Also didn't find anything like that in aws documentation.

> 1. Simply let the connection open and it will close by itself at some point.

This is how it handled at my company right now and in majority of examples I've found in the internet. It's pretty safe to leave connection opened. Server closes the connection if it's not used after some time. The time after which the connection is closed (keep-alive timeout) is configured on the server side. The default value is different for every server. E.g. for apache it's only 5-10 seconds.